# Rendering components with data passed as parameters to a page

Tags: blazor-server-side

On the click of a button, I am rendering a component on a page. This works
very well with my code below. The component is an input box that saves
data to the database

```
        <button type="button" @onclick="GenerateComponents" id="btClickMe">
            Show Sign Up Window
        </button>

        <div id="groups-parent" style="display: block; min-height: 500px; position: relative; border: dashed 1px #888; ">
            @foreach (var xAlert in sideItems)
            {
                <div class="draggable obstacle">
                    @xAlert
                </div>
            }
        </div>
                                    
        
        private async Task GenerateComponents()
        {
            sideItems.Add(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.OpenComponent<AddComponent>(0);
                    builder.CloseComponent();
                });
            
            StateHasChanged();
        }
```

When the page loads and there is data in the database, I will like to pass the database
data as parameters to the component and render on the page. There could be 10 of them.

With the code above, how can I achieve this? This is more like using the same page for the generation
and display of data from the database.

Let me try to explain further about what I am trying to achieve.

sideItems below is a list of renderFragment. It could have been nice if I can add database data to this
list and that will solve my problem but no I cant do that.

```
        public List<RenderFragment> sideItems { get; set; }
```

When my main page loads, I want to be able to call the GetData method and return data for each component on the page that is hosting
my component

```
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            sideItems = new List<RenderFragment>();
            //Pull GetData() here
        }
                
        
        public List<Tester> GetData()
        {
            List<Tester> data = new List<Tester>
            {
                new Tester{FirstName = "JJ", LastName = "PP"},
                new Tester{FirstName = "HH", LastName = "KK"},
                new Tester{FirstName = "KK", LastName = "LL"},
            };
            return data;
        }
```

I want to be able to use this Html page to display the component with associated data on my page
and still be able to click on the button to generate new components at the same time so on my page I have
a combination of components with data from the database and new components without data from the database.

```
        <div id="groups-parent" style="display: block; min-height: 500px; position: relative; border: dashed 1px #888; ">
            @foreach (var xAlert in sideItems)
            {
                <div class="draggable obstacle">
                    @xAlert
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: Does every click add a component?

Comment: Yes it does. Every click adds a component

Answer (score 0):

Edit after clarification by OP:

Wanting to render a list of items when each item is displayed with a razor component is a very common pattern. This is how you should do it:

**ListItem.razor**

```
// logic to render Value
First Name: @Value.FirstName
Last Name: @Value.LastName

@code
{
   [Parameter]
   public Tester Value {get;set;}

}
```

***Note that no particular type OR collection of component types (`List<RenderFragment>` or `List<ListItem>` Or even `List<Tester>`) is used.***

**ListHolder.razor**

```
<div>
   @ListComponents
</div>

@code
{
   [Parameter]
   public RenderFragment ListComponents {get;set;}
}
```

**Index.razor**

```
<ListHolder>

@foreach(var value in values)
{
  <ListItem Value="@value />
}
</ListHolder>

@code
{

    IEnumerable<Tester> values;
    // some data pull function, could sit in initialize/ use click event handler etc
   void PullData()
   {
      values = GetData(); 
      StateHasChanged();
   }


}
```

Earlier response:

Passing your db values as cascading parameter would let you pass data without explicitly assigning to a component. I will also suggest that you don't tinker with the builder if it is not absolutely required.
Try this:

```
        <button type="button" @onclick="GenerateComponents" id="btClickMe">
            Show Sign Up Window
        </button>

        <div id="groups-parent" style="display: block; min-height: 500px; position: relative; border: dashed 1px #888; ">
                <CascadingValue Value="@dbValue">, 
            @foreach (var componentIndex in componentCount)
            {
                <div class="draggable obstacle">
                    <PaneComponent/>
                </div>
            }
               </CascadingValue> 

        </div>

@code
{
        int componentCount = 0;
        private async Task GenerateComponents()
        {
            componentCount++;
                        
            StateHasChanged();
        }

}
```

Comment: My goal is to have the html section handle the generation of the component which is working now and on load of my page have a method to pull the data from the database and still use the same html to display the data. Side items is a list of renderfragment. So when database data is displayed on the page and users can still click on the button and add more components. Will this solution work for that?

Comment: Also the name of my component is AddComponent that has 2 parameters that can be passed to it.

Comment: It should work. However, I am not very clear what you trying to achieve functionally. Also, you can have multiple cascading parameters. In your case you can have two cascading parameters for AddComponent.

Comment: I don't quite understand how your solution will work. I added more notes to my question and maybe this will help you understand what I want to achieve. Are you able to modify my code to explain what you mean. What is PanelComponent? What is @dbvalue. Appreciate it.

Comment: Also in your code you removed all the builder code that is currently generating my component.

Comment: Blazor is declarative. You don't need to generate a component explicitly. Updated the answer based on your clarification.

Comment: I am confused. Now you have created two different answers. Can the new code you pasted be used in generating a blank component?

Comment: Ignore the earlier response. You can use the edited one as it is.

Comment: What is listitem, list holder, index? I don’t get it.

Comment: Also in your new code where is the button that will be generating a blank component? I can’t see that.

Comment: Blazor works little differently from some of the existing JS/TS based frameworks. I recommend go through this series. It will clear most of your doubts:  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4WEkbdagHIR0RBe_P4bai64UDqZEbQap

Comment: Again am I creating 3 different components? What are these components? What do they do?

Comment: I appreciate all your help but what will GenerateComponents now look like? We are very close.

Comment: You don't need GenerateComponents(). When the @foreach iterator runs, it will generate the components for you.

Comment: But what is my button click event calling?

Comment: In your index.razor you have a method to pull data - PullData() but I still want to be able to generate the component on a click of the button(multiple components) What will that method look like? I guess this is the only thing you are missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237957/discussion-between-baba-and-mayur-ekbote).